# Understanding the where clause in sqlx FromRow Macro Expansion

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I don't understand line 3 in the code below. It is a macro expansion of the FromRow trait in sqlx. I through that `'a` denoted a lifetime? It seems in this expansion it is being treated as a type and constrained? What does this line mean?

```
       impl<'a, R: ::sqlx::Row> ::sqlx::FromRow<'a, R> for LitRel
         where
         &'a ::std::primitive::str: ::sqlx::ColumnIndex<R>, //<--- ?
         String: ::sqlx::decode::Decode<'a, R::Database>,
         String: ::sqlx::types::Type<R::Database>,
```

Comment: It looks to me `&'a str` together, as a string slice, is a type and `'a` is its lifetime.

Comment: I see, thanks (if you post as an answer, I will accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me `&'a ::std::primitive::str` together is a type, string slice, and `'a` is its lifetime.

Comment: do you know why the lifetime is needed here in the where clause? (wouldn't it be enough to just constrain the type directly [i.e. remove &'a altogether?])

Comment: Sorry I have no knowledge of that. There is another thing strange to me. Per the sqlx::FromRow [documentation](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.1/sqlx/trait.FromRow.html), the macro should always generate a bound `usize: ColumnIndex<R>`. I don't know why for your case it is `&'a ::std::primitive::str`, instead of `usize`, is bound to `ColumnIndex<R>`. If it is a question for you too, maybe you can raise another question with more information of the struct `LitRel`.

Comment: Don't know, I'm using the sqlite database, maybe that is the reason?